# How can I get alerts to only show on a specific tab of a tabbed layout using MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have a view with a tabbed layout, and a form for each tab (using partials). I want to give feedback to the user on a per-tab basis, but also have my code be reusable.

So, the parent page:

```
<div id="detailsLayout">
@using (var tabs = Html.Bootstrap().Begin(new Tabs("TabsId")))
{
    @tabs.Tab(Html.LabelFor(m => m.course).ToString())
    @tabs.Tab(Html.LabelFor(m => m.baselineData).ToString())
    @tabs.Tab(Html.LabelFor(m => m.assessments).ToString())
    @tabs.Tab(Html.LabelFor(m => m.groups).ToString())


    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.course)</h2>
        Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Course");
    }
    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.baselineData)</h2>
        Html.RenderAction("Edit", "BaselineData");
    }
    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.assessments)</h2>
        Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Assessments");
    }
    using (tabs.BeginPanel())
    {
        <h2>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.groups)</h2>
        Html.RenderAction("Edit", "Groups");
    }
}
```

On each tab, I put a partial for notifications:

```
@{
    string successMsg = (string)TempData["successMsg"];
    string infoMsg = (string)TempData["infoMsg"];
    string warnMsg = (string)TempData["warnMsg"];
    string errMsg = (string)TempData["errMsg"];

    if (errMsg != null && errMsg != "")
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Alert(errMsg).Style(AlertColor.Danger)
    }
    if (warnMsg != null && warnMsg != "")
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Alert(warnMsg).Style(AlertColor.Warning)
    }
    if (successMsg != null  && successMsg != "")
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Alert(successMsg).Style(AlertColor.Success)
    }
    if (infoMsg != null  && infoMsg != "")
    {
        @Html.Bootstrap().Alert(infoMsg).Style(AlertColor.Info)
    }
}
```

I want to be able to do things in my controller like `TempData["infoMsg"]="This is a draft copy, you can commit changes by saving or roll back by reverting"`, but I only want it to apply to a specific view (tab)-- using my current method, all the views will display the message since it's pointing to `TempData`.

How can I steer the message to the correct page? I thought about adding a "forPage" argument somehow, but I am not sure how to modify the partial to accept it without using more TempData, which won't solve the problem.

Comment: I should also mention that each tab has its own unique div w/id and is being reloaded with ajax for submission/revert/etc. The controller that would send the message is for the child page (`CourseController` for example) and not the parent controller.

Comment: There might be a way to do it in MVC but I would approach this in a javascript way.  On the page load check the errMsg for each tab (maybe hidden form value) and then change the value inside the specific tab using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up adding a string model to the partial, then calling RenderAction:

### Partial view:

```
@model string
@{
    string successMsg = Model == null ? (string)TempData["successMsg"] : (string)TempData[Model + "SuccessMsg"];
    string infoMsg = Model == null ? (string)TempData["infoMsg"] : (string)TempData[Model + "InfoMsg"];
    string warnMsg = Model == null ? (string)TempData["warnMsg"] : (string)TempData[Model + "WarnMsg"];
    string errMsg = Model == null ? (string)TempData["errMsg"] : (string)TempData[Model + "ErrMsg"];

//the rest as above
```

### Controller action:

```
    public ActionResult NotificationPartial(string forPage)
    {
        return PartialView("_NotificationPartial", forPage);
    }
```

### The call from the view:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("NotificationPartial", "Home", new {forPage = "baselineData"});}
```

### The controller passing a message:

```
TempData["baselineDataSuccessMsg"] = "Baseline Data Saved.";
```

Comment: ***NOTE: After this change, I couldn't just call ```@Html.Partial(...)``` on this anymore. Ended up using the same call from the view, but passed null to trigger logic.